# My SQL statement with 2 INSERT commands is failing on the second INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following 2 `INSERT` statements:

```
-- Create a new database entry for the astronomicalObject in the GradObservers database
-- based on values of the given id
INSERT INTO astro.bodies (id, title, coordinates) 
    SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR bodies.nextid, title, 9291
    FROM astro.astro 
    WHERE id = 002811

-- Insert new id from table above into astro.sources
-- Insert other fields from existing bodyId 002811
INSERT INTO astro.sources(bodyId, baseValue, Url)
    (SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, current_value) FROM sys.sequences WHERE schema_id = 71)
    SELECT baseValue, Url 
    FROM astro.sources 
    WHERE bodyId = 002811
```

I'm trying to do 2 `INSERT` commands where the 2nd one depends on the `ID` value of the first one.

The first `INSERT` uses a `SEQUENCE` in the database to get it's `ID`.

Then the second `INSERT` needs to use that ID as well.

The first `INSERT` works, but I get an error from the 2nd statement:

> The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Your second insert is a syntax error, it should be `INSERT INTO astro.sources(bodyId, baseValue, Url) select(SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, current_value) FROM sys.sequences WHERE schema_id = 71), baseValue, Url FROM astro.sources WHERE bodyId = 002811`

Comment: @Stu but it's not telling me it's a syntax error, it's saying that I don't have enough items in the insert list...or is that caused by the syntax error?

Comment: You could try it and see - currently you're inserting a single value followed by a separate select statement....

Comment: Just as a side note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **completely unsupported** (out of even extended support) by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Comment: FYI, SQL Server 2008 ran *completely* out of support over *4 years ago*, you really should be upgrading your instance by now. Using such an old reason brings a wealth of security concerns and is irresponsible.

Comment: You specify 3 columns in the insert statement, but only inserting 1 column.  The error message is pretty clear.

Comment: *"but it's not telling me it's a syntax error"* then, if we need to be pedantic, you have a typographical error. The syntax you've used and the syntax your want aren't the same.

Comment: Though the method you've used isn't safe, it could suffer from race conditions. Why not use an `OUTPUT` clause in your first `INSERT` statement to get the generate `SEQUENCE` value(s)?

Comment: @ThomA do you mean like a temporary table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a single value being inserted, followed by a separate `SELECT` statement.

The correct syntax would have the nested `SELECT` inside the main `SELECT`. And for safety's sake you should probably use the sequence name.

```sql
INSERT INTO astro.sources
  (bodyId, baseValue, Url)
SELECT
  (
    SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, seq.current_value)
    FROM sys.sequences seq
    JOIN sys.schemas sch ON sch.schema_id = seq.schema_id
    WHERE sch.name = 'bodies'
      AND seq.name = 'nextid'
  ),
  baseValue,
  Url 
FROM astro.sources 
WHERE bodyId = 002811;
```

However you are probably better off just storing it in a variable in the first place.

```sql
DECLARE @id bigint = NEXT VALUE FOR bodies.nextid;

INSERT INTO astro.bodies
  (id, title, coordinates) 
SELECT
  @id,
  title,
  9291
FROM astro.astro 
WHERE id = 2811;

INSERT INTO astro.sources
  (bodyId, baseValue, Url)
SELECT
  @id,
  baseValue,
  Url 
FROM astro.sources 
WHERE bodyId = 2811;
```

Side note: `bodyId = 002811` doesn't make much sense. `002811` is a number not a string, so why does it have leading zeroes.